# MS Access Query to SQL Server Transform And Pivots

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, c#-4.0

I need to Convert Access Query to SQL Sever Query.

**qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths :**

```
SELECT t.JobId, t.AccountId, t.FinancialYear AS FinYear, t.Period, Sum(t.Amount) AS Amt
FROM (SELECT JobId, AccountId,FinancialYear, Period, Amount  FROM Temp_BlankBudgets 
union all 
SELECT JobId, AccountId,FinancialYear, Period, Amount  FROM Temp_Budgets)  AS t
GROUP BY t.JobId, t.AccountId, t.Period, t.FinancialYear
ORDER BY t.JobId, t.AccountId, t.Period;
```

**Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths :**

```
TRANSFORM Sum(qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.Amt) AS SumOfAmt
SELECT qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.JobId, qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.AccountId, qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.FinYear, Sum(qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.Amt) AS FYTotal
FROM qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths
GROUP BY qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.JobId, qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.AccountId, qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.FinYear
PIVOT qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths.Period;
```

**Final Query**

```
SELECT Temp_Accounts.AccountNumber, Temp_Accounts.AccountName,Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[1],Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[2], Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[3],Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[4], Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[5], 
Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[6], Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[7], 
Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[8], Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[9],  
Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[10], Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[11], 
Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.[12], Temp_Accounts.AccountID,Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.FYTotal 
FROM Temp_Accounts INNER JOIN Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths ON
Temp_Accounts.AccountID = Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths.AccountID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
--qry_BudgetForTwelveMonths :

SELECT 
    t.JobId
    , t.AccountId
    , t.FinancialYear AS FinYear
    , t.Period
    , Sum(t.Amount) AS Amt 
INTO #tmp1
FROM (SELECT 
            JobId
            , AccountId
            ,FinancialYear
            , Period
            , Amount 
    FROM Temp_BlankBudgets 
    union all 
    SELECT 
    JobId
    , AccountId
    ,FinancialYear
    , Period
    , Amount 
    FROM Temp_Budgets) AS t 
GROUP BY t.JobId, t.AccountId, t.Period, t.FinancialYear 
ORDER BY t.JobId, t.AccountId, t.Period;

--Qry_CrstabJobBudgetForTwelveMonths :
SELECT *
INTO #tmp2
FROM (
        SELECT 
            a.JobId
            , a.AccountId
            , a.FinancialYear
            , Sum(a.Amount) AS FYTotal 
        FROM #tmp a
        GROUP BY a.JobId, a.AccountId, a.FinancialYear 
    ) AS SOURCE
PIVOT
    (
    Sum(a.Amount) AS SumOfAmt 
    FOR BMonth IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
    ) AS PVT
ORDER BY BMonth
--Final Query

SELECT 
    Temp_Accounts.AccountNumber
    , Temp_Accounts.AccountName
    , b.[1]
    , b.[2]
    , b.[3]
    , b.[4]
    , b.[5]
    , b.[6]
    , b.[7]
    , b.[8]
    , b.[9]
    , b.[10]
    , b.[11]
    , b.[12]
    , Temp_Accounts.AccountID
    , b.FYTotal 
FROM Temp_Accounts 
INNER JOIN #tmp2 b 
    ON Temp_Accounts.AccountID = b.AccountID
```